# How to get Visual Studio to show hints and warning in a web-site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms, vs-web-site-project

When you build a web-site in Visual Studio, it will not show you any Hints or Warning related to `aspx` markup files unless you have the file physically open in the editor.

For example, there is a **Hint** related to my `Default.aspx` file. But right now i only have the `aspx.cs` file visible:

[image]

If i build the solution (or Rebuild the solution, or Build the web-site, or re-build the web-site (whatever those different options mean)):

[image]

i get no hints or warnings about my web-site or solution:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: D:\...\WebSite\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/WebSite/App_Code/'.
Building directory '/WebSite/Account/'.
Building directory '/WebSite/'.
Building directory '/WebSite/Scripts/'.

Validation Complete
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Nor do i get any hints or warnings about my web-site or solution:

[image]

But if i simply press <kbd>F7</kbd> to make the markup file appear:

[image]

And build my solution (or rebuild my solution, or build my web-site, or rebuild my web-site (whatever those different options mean)), i get hints and warnings related to `Default.aspx`:

[image]

## How do i make Visual Studio its job?

The only workaround i've been able to come up with is to open each file in the web-site, switch to the "designer" view, and then build the solution (or rebuild the solution, or build the web-site, or rebuild the web-site (whatever those different options mean)). When you have 60 or 70 pages, that gets quite tedious:

[image]

But at least i then get to see the hints and warnings in the web-site solution:

[image]

Is there a way to convince Visual Studio to build the *entire* solution? (Or rebuild the *entire* solution? Or build the *entire* web-site? Or rebuild the *entire* web-site? (Whatever those different options mean))